# How can I use renewcommand for toprule of the booktabs package?

Tags: macros, booktabs

I have a LaTeX document and want to change the thickness of `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` to 1.5pt.
Is there a way to do this with the `\renewcommand` or do I have to change every `\toprule` to `\toprule[1.5pt]`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: 1.5pt would show *very* thick rules.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default width of those rules is defined by the length `\heavyrulewidth`, so you can change this with `\setlength\heavyrulewidth{<length>}`. For example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\setlength\heavyrulewidth{1.5pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c}
\toprule
Some text \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```